# Read promotion rule condition - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to read the condition of a shopping cart price rule in magento programatically.

`Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule` has a method `getConditionsSerialized()` which does provide the conditions but in a cryptic manner to say the least such as the following:

```
a:7:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";s:10:"conditions";a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_address";s:9:"attribute";s:13:"base_subtotal";s:8:"operator";s:2:">=";s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";b:0;}}}
```

Does anyone know how to read the condition in a more humane way plz? I'd like to be able to read certain attributes.

Thanks a bunch!

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use php's [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function to convert this to a workable array.

Try this:

```
$conditions = unserialize($rule->getConditionsSerialized());
print_r($conditions);
```

I've blogged before about how these work, and while my post is about *creating* rules, it still explains a bit about how you might come to understand conditions.

[Here's my post](http://mikebywaters.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/programmatically-create-shopping-cart-price-rules-with-conditions-and-actions/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

`unserialize($rule->getConditionsSerialized()`) did the trick!

Hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

Magento already implements a function to unserialize conditions and actions for itself, all you have to do is use it.

`$conditions = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rules')->load($ruleId)->getConditions();`

Each call to `->getConditions()` will get you deeper conditions within executing rule object.

For example, first time you call `->getConditions()` it will return an object type of `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Combine` that's the default wrapper for all inner conditions. If you chain the call again `->getConditions()->getConditions()` you'll get an array with [X] of condition objects, each one of the type you declared when creating them through adminhtml interface.

Avoid using `unserialize()` and start using Magento built-in functions.